Acrobat: transfer 'sign yourself' signature between laptops
Adobe Acrobat has a 'sign yourself' function that allows the use of signatures and initials:

How do I transfer my 'sign yourself' signature from the old laptop to the new one?
I'm in the process of transferring my stuff between laptops, and I'd prefer to keep using the exact same one, rather than drawing a new one.
unfortunately the information I find when searching for this problem tends to refer to e-signatures that employ some kind of digital identification, rather than this fairly simple visual Acrobat function.
This refers to Adobe Acrobat Pro version 2024.004.20243 (x64), on both devices (also both Win10).

What sort of signature have you configured on the old computer? Is it just an image of your signature?

If you click the plus above, you get a drawing window - I signed there on the spot, using my touchscreen.

I don't know if this is part of a paid service, but Adobe reports they sync your signature here: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/capture-and-sync-your-signature.html Also, if you're just interested in the image of the signature, you save your signature as an image file, and use that to create your signature in the application. So long as you use the same signature image as the source, it'll stay the same on each subsequent device.

Interesting! I'm logged onto the same Adobe account on both devices, clearly it's not syncing that signature though. No 'save as image' function there unfortunately, and a screenshot will be pretty small / low res.

Just doublechecked on the new laptop, and 'save online' is not available on this version of Acrobat Pro. Perhaps it's a mobile only function.

Not to solve this problem, but to solve it going forward. Use a touchscreen or your mobile device to create an image of your signature. When you create the signature in the new client, go to Preferences > Signatures > New, and choose the Imported Graphic option, and select that image you created. Save that image somewhere safe and you'll be able to use it again whenever you need to recreate your signature.

The signature can be exported in .cer, .fdf or .p7c formats, but you need .p12 or .pfx to send it to your new computer.
If you originally created the signature as a  PKCS#12 file, then it should be easy to find that .pfx file in this location on Windows:
Users>username>AppData>Roaming>Adobe>Acrobat>DC>Security
Once that file is transferred, then use the Add ID function

There are several ways Adobe uses signatures, so from the comments, I gather a pen / mouse / finger / touchscreen was used for a drawn moniker. Such as my "Mark" here in a text file but can be any form of PDF or even a gov.XFA.

Such signatures will be stored in the cloud account for verification. And the drawing placed into the pdf. (Neither as a key secured signature nor image).
If it was an image it would be easily extractable the same as extracting a signature key.
However the vector drawing will look like this and be reusable as a PDF object (stamp) but not normally as reusable as an image would be.
<</Length 2938/Matrix[1 0 0 1 262.09709 652.34646]/Type/XObject/Subtype/Form/FormType 1/Resources<</ProcSet[/PDF]>>/ADBE_FillSign<</Type/FillSignData/Subtype/signature>>/BBox[0 0 59.918764 69.67297]>>
stream
q
1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
.658448 0 0 .657292 0 0 cm
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 RG 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 rg 1 J 1 j 1.908 w 7.587 60.314 m 7.587 60.314 7.587 60.314 7.746 60.314 c S 1.908 w 7.746 60.314 m 7.904 60.314 8.222 60.314 8.793 60.314 c S 1.908 w 8.793 60.314 m 9.365 60.314 10.190 60.314 11.177 60.314 c S 1.908 w 11.177 60.314 m 12.165 60.314 13.315 60.314 13.890 60.314 c S 1.908 w 13.890 60.314 m 14.465 60.314 14.465 60.314 18.327 62.349 c S 1.908 w 18.327 62.349 m 22.190 64.384 29.915 68.455 37.555 72.589 c S 1.908 w 37.555 72.589 m 45.196 76.723 52.751 80.920 58.947 84.385 c S 1.908 w 58.947 84.385 m 65.143 87.850 69.981 90.583 73.681 92.718 c S 1.908 w 73.681 92.718 m 77.381 94.854 79.943 96.393 81.729 97.536 c S 1.908 w 81.729 97.536 m 83.516 98.678 84.527 99.425 85.077 100.021 c S 1.908 w 85.077 100.021 m 85.627 100.618 85.715 101.064 85.622 101.536 c S 1.908 w 85.622 101.536 m 85.529 102.007 85.253 102.503 83.244 104.304 c S 1.908 w 65.785 66.674 m 65.785 66.674 65.785 66.674 65.721 66.706 c S 1.908 w 65.721 66.706 m 65.658 66.738 65.531 66.801 65.245 66.992 c S 1.908 w 65.245 66.992 m 64.959 67.183 64.515 67.501 63.744 67.998 c S 1.908 w 63.744 67.998 m 62.973 68.495 61.876 69.172 60.573 69.951 c S 1.908 w 60.573 69.951 m 59.271 70.729 57.762 71.609 56.070 72.495 c S 1.908 w 56.070 72.495 m 54.378 73.381 52.503 74.272 50.550 75.195 c S 1.908 w 50.550 75.195 m 48.597 76.118 46.566 77.074 44.333 78.219 c S 1.908 w 44.333 78.219 m 42.100 79.364 39.666 80.699 37.406 81.989 c S 1.908 w 37.406 81.989 m 35.146 83.278 33.061 84.523 31.288 85.592 c S 1.908 w 31.288 85.592 m 29.514 86.660 28.052 87.552 26.902 88.315 c S 1.908 w 26.902 88.315 m 25.751 89.077 24.913 89.712 24.242 90.249 c S 1.908 w 24.242 90.249 m 23.571 90.787 23.069 91.227 22.654 91.649 c S 1.908 w 22.654 91.649 m 22.238 92.071 21.911 92.473 21.610 92.893 c S 1.908 w 21.610 92.893 m 21.309 93.312 21.035 93.747 20.757 94.173 c S 1.908 w 20.757 94.173 m 20.479 94.599 20.196 95.017 19.835 95.451 c S 1.908 w 19.835 95.451 m 19.475 95.885 19.037 96.337 18.618 96.777 c S 1.908 w 18.618 96.777 m 18.199 97.217 17.799 97.645 17.414 97.992 c S 1.908 w 17.414 97.992 m 17.030 98.339 16.661 98.605 16.332 98.889 c S 1.908 w 16.332 98.889 m 16.003 99.174 15.715 99.476 15.397 99.762 c S 1.908 w 15.397 99.762 m 15.080 100.049 14.733 100.319 14.344 100.631 c S 1.908 w 14.344 100.631 m 13.954 100.942 13.522 101.294 13.088 101.661 c S 1.908 w 13.088 101.661 m 12.654 102.028 12.219 102.411 11.734 102.761 c S 1.908 w 11.734 102.761 m 11.250 103.112 10.717 103.431 10.230 103.681 c S 1.908 w 10.230 103.681 m 9.744 103.931 9.304 104.112 8.928 104.300 c S 1.908 w 8.928 104.300 m 8.552 104.487 8.240 104.681 8.027 104.859 c S 1.908 w 8.027 104.859 m 7.815 105.038 7.701 105.201 7.644 105.282 c S 1.908 w 7.644 105.282 m 7.587 105.364 7.587 105.364 7.587 105.364 c S 1.908 w 7.587 105.364 m 7.587 105.364 7.587 105.364 7.587 105.364 c S
Q

endstream
endobj

Thus if you do not have an Adobe "cloud stored" importable copy it will be hard for you to replace those vectors, "exactly the same", in another machine. I can cut and paste such a "Mark" programmatically but not so easily reuse it, except as a stamped signature on other documents.




Wouldn't it be possible to use the PDF document itself as the vector image? (AFAIK that's common practice in macOS world, at least.) 2) What software are you using to extract the individual objects from the PDF?

